# Rewrite the referer header when using ngrok

Tags: ngrok

I want to create an ngrok tunnel to a router admin web interface that requires the `Referer` header to be set to the router's base URL, any request without the `Referer` set to (in my case) `http://192.168.1.1/` will fail with a HTTP 403.

I've been trying to use the `--request-header-add` option:

```
ngrok http --request-header-add 'referer: http://192.168.1.1/' 192.168.1.1:80
```

but it complains about wrong format, since the value contains a colon in the `http://` part:

```
ERROR:  Added request header should be in key:value format, got referer: http://192.168.1.1/
ERROR:
ERROR:  ERR_NGROK_370
```

Is there really no way to rewrite / add a referer header?

Comment: show what you tried

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with router (opnsense) and I fixed it be removing the referer header all together (as I did not find a way to set it using ngrok)

e.g.:

`ngrok http --host-header=rewrite --request-header-remove 'referer' 192.168.1.1:80`

Comment: Great suggestion! Unfortunately, TP-Link's developers have based some ridiculous "security" logic around the referer header, so even if I remove the header I still get a 403 on all requests. Seems that the only way is to run a small secondary proxy between ngrok and the web admin service with the only purpose of rewriting the header, which is a shame :/

Answer (score 0):

One way I have made it work was passing a value as a string.

```
ngrok http --request-header-add "referer: ${URL}" 192.168.1.1:80
```

By making it double quotes instead of single ones and making the URL a variable.

Hope that helps you.